# What the "self" refers to in closure - Swift

Tags: swift

I am having a hard time understanding what is truly happening in a closure in `Swift` and was hoping that someone could help me understand.

```
class MyClass {

    func printWhatever(words: String) {
        print(words)
    }

    func doWhatever() {
         dispatch_async(...) {   
              //why self      
              self.printWhatever("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

On the line `self.printWhatever("Hello")`, why do I have to use `self`? `xCode` always just tells me that I have to, but I am not sure why. So, my question is what exactly is stored in the closure. I know a closure captures the surrounding context. But how much? Is the instance of `MyClass` captured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a matter of clarity. Any time you use a method or property name without an explicit recipient, it is implicitly being sent to `self`. But in an anonymous function you must make this fact explicit. If you were to say

```
printWhatever("Hello")
```

...you might not realize that you are implicitly capturing `self`. So you might not realize that, if this anonymous function were [itself to be stored](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#SECweakSelf) somewhere in `self`, you can wind up with a dreaded *retain cycle*. Therefore, the compiler *forces* you to say `self` *explicitly*, so that you are aware of the implications of your own actions.

The proof of this is that there are circumstances where you do *not* have to say `self` in an anonymous function. Consider this:

```
func printWhatever(words: String) {
    print(words)
}

func doThis(f:()->()) {
    f()
}

func doWhatever() {
    doThis {
        self.printWhatever("Hello") // self is required
    }
}
```

In the above, you *must* say `self`, because the compiler has no guarantee that a retain cycle might not happen. But now watch what happens if we add the `@noescape` attribute:

```
func printWhatever(words: String) {
    print(words)
}

func doThis(@noescape f:()->()) { // *
    f()
}

func doWhatever() {
    doThis {
        printWhatever("Hello") // ok!
    }
}
```

The `@noescape` attribute *guarantees* that the passed function will be executed immediately and not stored. Thus `self` is no longer required, because no retain cycle can take place.

Personally, I *always* say `self` wherever I am allowed to, as a matter of style. And I suggest you do the same.

---

NOTE: There was a language-change [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0009-require-self-for-accessing-instance-members.md) that was [rejected](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160104/005478.html), and one of the grounds for rejection was the very one that I give:

> The requirement to use `self.` within potentially-escaping closures is a useful indicator of the potential for retain cycles

Comment: +1 for "always saying `self` where allowed".  At the very least it avoids extra editing to add `self` when a body gets elevated to a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Is the instance of MyClass captured?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is required to capture the instance of the object you want to send the message. Without it the compiler doesn't know who to send the message.
Pay attention that sometimes having `self` into a clojure can lead to reference cycle, basically the captured object will never be released, in htis case you should create a capture list inside the clojure and specify a different memory manage such as `unowned` or `weak`